# Messaging is sending a large number of SMS messages POPUP

Tags: android

I'm developing SMS application which sends a lot of SMS's from a database.But when  I'm sending SMS  appears a popup "Messaging is sending a large number of SMS messages. Do you want to allow this app to continue sending messages?".How I can avoid this poup??

Comment: Send fewer SMS messages.  That's an anti-spam feature, added to prevent apps from sending SMSes in the background like crazy, costing the user money and clogging the network.

Answer (score 3):

SMS sending limit was introduced not later than Gingerbread. As far as I know, and I investigated thoroughly, it is generally impossible to override these limits on non-rooted devices. If possible, those are rare exceptions. But, if your app is supposed to send messages from your device only or from controlled number of devices, you may get around this problem by setting SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_MAX_COUNT to a huge number (say 99999) in:

- /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

  1. table *secure*
  2. table *system*
- /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db

  1. table *main*

Comment: says no permission on those dirs. Q: Does it require root??

Comment: yeah these table (db) of secure and system setting are not completely exposed. Although some of settings are acesible but for these sort of modification of table would require root

Comment: Is there maybe another way by now? This is an essential feature of my App and the user knows about it..

Answer (score -2):

```
   int numOfMsg=200;
 final Timer s=new Timer();
    s.schedule(new TimerTask() {

   @Override
    public void run() {
    SmsManager mysmsmanager=SmsManager.getDefault();

if(numOfMsg<200){

        mysmsmanager.sendTextMessage("Num", null,"Num",null,null);                                                          
numOfMsg++;                         
}           
else {
s.cancel();
}                           

 }
  }, 2000,5000);
```

Comment: Code without explanation is pretty unhelpful